# Cannot add new row after set DataSource in gridview winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using EF to get data source for dataGridView, after set DataSource, everything work well but dataGridView was not show `add new row`.

Code:

```
LkvDbContext db = new LkvDbContext();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Accounts.ToList();
```

[image: cannot add new row]

but if I don't set DataSource there is not issue.

[image]

this is database code:

```
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }        
        public string Cookiechat { get; set; }
        public int Role { get; set; }
        public int Department { get; set; }
    }
    public class LkvDbContext : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

anyone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `BindingList` as in `JohnNguyen` answer or using `BindingSource` which I'll describe below:

```
List<Account> accounts = dbContext.Accounts.ToList();
BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
src.Datasource = accounts;
dataGridview1.Datasource = src;
```

Comment: may be you misunderstand I mean. I try with `List<Account>` but cannot.
My code:

    `var l = new List<Account>();
            l.Add(new Account (){Username="dfs",Password = "sdfsd"});
            dataGridView1.DataSource = l;`

Comment: Understood, in this case, you should use `BindingList` which is describe in @JohnNguyen answer, or `BindingSource` which I will edit in my answer

Comment: Exactly, your answer is correct. but just now, you edited your answer
Thanks. are u form vietnamese? nice to meet you

Comment: Yes, I'm from Viet Nam, nice to meet you too. I misunderstood his question at first, therefore I made an edit to correct it

Answer (score 2):

I found down solution. because `List<Account>` and `DbSet<Account>` is not inherit from IBindingList interface. this is solition:

```
 var data = new BindingList<Account>(db.Accounts.ToList());
 dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```